# Castle Windsor - intercept method and cast it to Action class

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, interceptor

how to cast the method invocation as an `Action` class including its arguments ? Is it even possible ?

```
Queue<Action> queue = new Queue<Action>();
```

sample method to be intercepted:

```
public string DoSomeStuff(string[] arr)
{
    //some logic here
}
```

interceptor (Castle Windsor):

```
public class MyInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        if (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(() => {
                 //here, add intercepted method (DoSomeStuff) and its parameters
            });
        }                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Enqueuing is straight forward:

```
public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
{
    queue.Enqueue(invocation.Proceed);
    ...
}
```

But this is pretty pointless since you will have to wait until the delegate is dequeued and invoked before returning from your Intercept() method.